# meaning of a parenthetical expression : all the more

Tags: phrase-meaning, parenthesis

What does "all the more" mean in the following? I cannot find its definition in the dictionary.

> How does one go out on top and, **all the more**, do it with grace?

Here, the context is about a person who is leaving a position.

Answer (score 1):

You could paraphrase it with **furthermore** or **moreover**. It is similar to **what's more**.

> He left, and what's more, he left in style.

But to my ear it's a little odd.  I haven't really ever *heard* **all the more** used in that manner, and cannot recall any book where it was used that way.

When I've heard it used, it was used like this:

> When a cool kid at school has such a widget, most kids will want one all the more.
>
> He loved her all the more for her fiery temper.

and there it could be glossed as "even more" or "that much more".  Lurking in this locution **the more** is an ossified instrumental-case *comparative* that has survived from a time when English was a declined language like its Germanic cousins.

Comment: Do you find the OP example a little odd as well?

Comment: The usage in your example is what I found odd.

Comment: Can it be rewritten as "How does one go out on top, and that with grace"?

Comment: That's grammatical, but it feels a little wooden / 18th century to me. ...and do so.... or ...and do it....  would be more natural in 2018.

Comment: But that could be my AmE ear.   Someone living in Aberdeen or Glasgow might well find it natural.

Answer (score 0):

First, the essential meaning of the sentence (if the parenthetical information is removed) is:

> How does one go out on top and do it with grace?

---

In this context, the phrase *all the more* could be replaced with the following phrases:

> How does one go out on top and, *furthermore*, do it with grace?
>   How does one to out on top and, *more than that*, do it with grace?

To rephrase the sentence, it's saying this:

> How does one *not only* go out on top *but also* do it with grace?

---

**Update**: In response to a comment left here, I conducted my own Google search and came up with many references to the expression.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20the%20more):

> : even more
>   // The fact that they'd written the play themselves made it *all the more* impressive.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-the-more):

> **even more than before**:
>   *Several publishers rejected her book, but that just made her all the more determined.*

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-the-more):

> All is used in structures such as all the more or all the better to mean even more or even better than before.
>   *The living room is decorated in pale colours that make it all the more airy.*
>   *'How are you?'—'All the better for seeing you.'*

Comment: "all the more" in this case cannot be found in the dictionary. Could you find a reference?

Comment: @Apollyon I didn't bother looking for it as you had already indicated you couldn't find it—and because I already understood the phrase as a native speaker. However, a quick search turned up multiple references for me, which I've added to the answer.

Comment: The examples of "all the more" you found are used differently from the OP example; they are all followed by adjectives.

Comment: Do you find the use of "all the more" in the OP natural?